# How to display datatable row in one line?

Tags: css, html, jsf, primefaces

I have a Primefaces datatable with many colums, but one of them contains long entries like 1000 characters or more. I would like to display each of that long entry in one line, not the whole entry of course, just the beginning of it, like: "the beginning of ..." instead of "the beginning of a very loooooooooong entry". The datatable is editable, so when the cell is edited, it should be expanded to view the whole entry. Is there any simple way to achieve it? I didn't find any suitable datatable or column attribute to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should put a `<p:commandButton>` at the location of this line.
This button will open a dialog (`<p:dialog>`) where you can edit the line.

To display a string with ellipsis, you can do the following in the managed bean:

```
    private String longString;
    ...
    public String getLongString() {
        return longString.substring(0, 10) + "...";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for an idea. But I still cannot display long entries just in one line (e.g. the beginning of entry with ellipsis).

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. It's quite suitable solution though I'm wondering if there's any e.g css property to solve my problem...

Comment: You can do it from client's side with `Jquery Ellipsis Plugin` : http://plugins.jquery.com/ellipsis/